# display first line from formatted text with ckeditor

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I saved formatted text using CKEditor in my database. Now I want to display first line from it in my ASP. NET MVC project.

I've already tried these snippets of code:

```
@Html.Raw(item.Description.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }).FirstOrDefault())
```

and

```
@WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Regex.Replace(item.Description.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }).FirstOrDefault(), "<[^>]*(>|$)", string.Empty))
```

but none of them work for me.

Comment: Provide more info. What was the text? What was the result/error?

Comment: There is no error. When I run my solution nothing is showed on browser. Without this code ---> Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }).FirstOrDefault() <--- that displays whole text.

Comment: Did you check what you tried to Split? I mean what value item.Description has? I think that your value is already wrapped by tag. That's why you have got nothing after Regex.Replace operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
@Html.Raw(Regex.Replace(news.Description, @"<[^>]*>", "").Substring(0, 80) + "...")
```